# How do I improve the runtime complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: java, time-complexity

```
public static boolean PP(int[] A){

    int n = A.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++){             //finds one value in the array
        for(int j = (i+1); j < n; j++){         //compares all the other values with that one value
            if (A[i] * A[j] == 225){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;               //returns false if it goes through the entire for loop without returning true
}
```

This code takes an array and tries to find two numbers that multiply to 225. If it finds two numbers then it returns true. Currently the running time is O(n^2) but I want to get a faster running time like O(nlogn) or O(n). So how do I decrease the running time of this?

Comment: Provide some description about what the code is supposed to do and why do you want to make it worse by **increasing** time :)

Comment: Order of growth != running time

Comment: You could turn one of the lists into a set, then iterate the other list and see whether the difference to 255 is in the set.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `O(n)` solution. You can use `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`. Insert (accumulatively)  all elements from `a` with their count in `HashMap<Integer, Integer> c` and:

```
for (int e : a) {
     if (225 % e == 0) {
         int t = 225/e;
         if (c.containsKey(t)) {
             if (t == e) {
                 if c.get(t) >= 2)
                     return true;
             }
             else
                 return true;
         }
     }
}  
return false;
```

Comment: The product is 225, not 255.

Comment: And don't you want to divide by `e` instead of `a`?

Comment: Strictly speaking you'd have to deal with `15` separately. At the moment this would return true if `15` were in the array, whereas the original code required `15` to appear twice. The same goes for `-15`.

Comment: Still haven't dealt with a single occurrence of 15. Current solution is effectively `if (225 % e == 0) return true;`

Comment: Here's a test case: `int[] a = { 15, 5, 45 }` What does your method yield?

Comment: @erickson `true` but it used to return `false`. Honestly, I didn't think that this corner would cause so much problem ( at least for me). Can't thank you enough

Comment: @erickson Thanks for being such a cool guy, trying to help out the others. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the array and then iterate over each element and find suitable element using binary search. Time complexity : O(N*logN) :

```
public static boolean PP(int[] A){

    int N = A.length;

    Arrays.sort(A);
    for (int i = 0;i<N-2;i++){
        int a = A[i];
        if (a == 0)
            continue;
        int seek = 225 / a;
        int res = Arrays.binarySearch(A, i+1,N,seek);
        if(res>0 && A[res]*a==225)
            return true;
    }
    return false;               //returns false if it goes through the entire for loop without returning true
}
```

Comment: @tobias_k's approach should be O(n) assuming you have a uniform hash distribution.

Answer (score 2):

So you just simply want to find 2 values within an array that results to 225 when multiplied, and return true and instantly break the loop when found.

Iterate through A, and divide 225 by each value.
Check if the hashset contains A[i], return true if it does.
Else, store the division result in a hash set.
Return false once you are done iterating through your array.

This should work because when `A * B = 225`, `B = 225 / A`.

This way, if we know A, we know what "B" will result true.

By storing A in a hashset, and you ever encounter a B where 225 / B is already in the hashset (which can be done in O(1)), then you know that you have your A * B = 225 pair.

By using a hashset, you can compare one value to the rest of the values in O(1), enabling you to compare all value in an array to every other value in O(n) time.

```
Set<Double> mySet = new HashSet<Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    double val = 225 / (double) A[i];
    if (mySet.contains(val)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!mySet.contains((Double)A[i]) {
        mySet.add((Double)A[i]);
    }
}
return false;
```

Now note that I'm not putting all the values in in the hashset first and comparing everything. I'm comparing as I add to the hashset (This will still ensure that you have compared all values to each other once!) see below graphic:

```
// The below represents the above algo on an array with 10 elements.
// The values 0 ~ 9 are the index.
// The left row is my insert, and top row is my "compare." 
// Every intersection "[]" means that the value has been compared to each other.

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0     [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
1        [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
2           [] [] [] [] [] [] []
3              [] [] [] [] [] []
4                 [] [] [] [] []
5                    [] [] [] []
6                       [] [] []
7                          [] []
8                             []
9 

// You can see that every value actually compares to each other (except
// for itself. More on this below)
```

I have not added everything to the hashset first, and went with the "compare as we add" method because it has room for *possibly* unwanted error:

If by any chance you have a single instance of the value 15 within your array, you will compare 15 with itself this way, causing you to get 225 and returning true, but you may actually want a "unique" pair. (Now this is up to what kind of problem you are solving)

If by any chance your array was simply `{ 15 }`, do you want to return `true`?

If your answer is true, switch the code around to add first, compare next:

```
Set<Double> mySet = new HashSet<Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    double val = 225 / (double) A[i];
    if (!mySet.contains((Double)A[i]) {
        mySet.add((Double)A[i]);
    }
    if (mySet.contains(val)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create `int B[]` containing `B[k]=255/A[k] - O(n)` (discard the elements which are not perfect divisor)
2. order A and B - O(n logn)
3. search for common elements in the two ordered arrays - O(n)